# Div Styled As Table for Form Input not Rendering

Tags: php, html, css

I'm working on a php powered site for a musician, part of which involves the ability for him to add upcoming shows to his site through a form. I want a table layout where he can see his upcoming shows, and can choose to add a new one. I tried using a table, but quickly found they don't really work with PHP forms. So I tried to format my form as a table with CSS display properties. That had it not rendering at all, in fact, if you go into the inspector in Chrome,it shows all of the information clearly there, laid out in the HTML, but with no height. I tried manually adding height and width, but to no avail. I tried changing from a form to a div, just to see, and that didn't help either.

```css
.form-table {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.admin-table-row {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}
.admin-table-cell {
    display: table-column;
}
.admin-venue {
    width: auto;
    text-align: left;
}
.admin-age {
    text-align: right;
    width: 75px;
}
.admin-date {
    text-align: right;
    width: 200px;
}
.admin-time {
    text-align: right;
    width: 100px;
}
.admin-time {
    text-align: right;
    width: 100px;
}
.admin-edit {
    text-align: right;
    width: 100px;
}
.admin-delete {
    text-align: right;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
//echo "<form class='form-table' action='' method='post'>";
echo "<div class='form-table'>";
foreach($stmt as $upcomingShow)
{
    $date = date("j F, Y", (strtotime($upcomingShow['date'])));
    $time = date("g:i a", (strtotime($upcomingShow['time'])));

    echo "<div class='admin-table-row'>";
        if(!empty($upcomingShow['link']))
        {
            echo "<div class='admin-venue admin-table-cell'><a href='" . $upcomingShow['link'] . "' style='text-decoration: none;'>" . $upcomingShow['venue'] . "</a></div>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<div class='admin-venue admin-table-cell'>" . $upcomingShow['venue'] . "</div>";   
        }
        echo "<div class='admin-age admin-table-cell'>" . $upcomingShow['age'] . "</div>";
        echo "<div class='admin-date admin-table-cell'>" . $date . "</div>";
        echo "<div class='admin-time admin-table-cell'>" . $time . "</div>";
        echo "<div class='admin-edit admin-table-cell'><input name='edit' id='edit' type='submit' value='  Edit  ' style='background: none; border: none; padding: 0; font: inherit; cursor: pointer;'></div>";
        echo "<div class='admin-delete admin-table-cell'><input name='delete' id='delete' type='submit' value='  Delete  ' style='background: none; border: none; padding: 0; font: inherit; cursor: pointer;'></div>";
        echo "<input name='show-id' id='show-id' type='hidden' value='" . $upcomingShow['id'] . "'>";
    echo "</div>";
}
echo "</div>";
//echo "</form>";
```

Thanks for all the help. Best, Chris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking your CSS, the issue is in here:

```
.admin-table-cell {
    display: table-column;
}
```

The `display: table-column` is not used to specify that the element is a cell, but to specify that the element contains a column of cells; and [**by definition it is not rendered**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html):

> Elements with 'display' set to 'table-column' or 'table-column-group' are not rendered (exactly as if they had 'display: none')

That's why you don't see the contents even after setting a `height`. What you need to use to specify that the `div` is a cell, is `display: table-cell`. Then it will display the content of each cell correctly. This change should fix the issue:

```
.admin-table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I had just googled around for the CSS as I had never done it and found some random question where it had used table-column haha. Thanks for the simple fix.